# State machine/ State chart in-cycle transition

Tags: simulink, state-machine, plc, statechart

If a state machine is called periodically (in MatLAB Simulink or PLC program), is it possible to transition between states during the same plc cycle/simulink step?.

In Twincat 3 (PLC) there is such an option "Cycle-internal" as in link below: 
https://infosys.beckhoff.com/content/1033/tf1910_tc3_uml/63050395607969163.html

are there any constraints to use such option? would the system still be real time capable?

Edited as I can't write a long comment:

1- In your example, If the  state is an In-Cycle state and is responsible for generating set points for the motor till it reaches the required set point (hence taking a lot of time). The program can be "stuck" in this state causing a task overrun, and violating the real time constraints. 
Suggested solution: Control the max. number of calls for this state with the variable "Max. DO cycle calls" :  https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tf1910_tc3_uml/63050395607969163.html&id=, or is it possible/better to implement this task in a separate PLC task?

2- For a state chart with no In-Cycle states, the program stops excuting the chart, saves the states, and execute the rest of the program after ONE evaluation of the current active state(s). 
If all states in the chart are In-Cycle, where does the program stops excuting the chart to execute the rest of the program?

Is the only solution is to have some states that are not In-Cycle and making sure they are reached fast enough not to cause a task overrun?

Comment: The generation of setpoints is done in a separate nc-task and is not controlled directly by you.In a plc the function blocks are not "blocking" unlike in non real time environments.You can have a cycle task overflow when you have a infinite loop for example or when you have a too small cycle time for your program.

Comment: The In-Cycle option just gives you the opportunity to react to a state-change in the current cycle or for example 10ms later in the next cycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A PLC is **made** to be real time capable, so to answer your last question, yes the system is real time capable regardless of the programming language you are using.

When you use the tf1910 extension, code for the Beckhoff runtime is generated in the background, which will run **cyclically** every x ms depending on your configurations.

Translating the Cycle-Internal operation to a structured language could look like this:

Imagine you have a software-component *Motor* which extends a software-component  *StateMachine*.

StateMachine defines different (primitive) states like *Init, Ready, Busy, Idle, Error etc*.

```
                               V  Boot()                        
                               |                                     
                               |
                            <Init>
                               |
                               |    
                               |  Start()
                               |
                               |
                            <Ready> -----------<--------------+-------------<-----------+
                               |                              |                         |
                               |                              |                         |
                               |  Execute()                   |                         |
                               |                              |                         |
                               |                              |                         |
                               |                              |   Reset()               |
                           <Prepare>                          |                         |
                               |                              |                         |
                               |                              |                         |
                               |                              |                         |
               Wait()          |           Fault()            |                         |
 <Waiting> ---<-------->--- <Busy> ----------->----------- <Error>                      |
              EndWait()        |                                                        |
                               |                                                        |
                               |                                                        |
                               |                                                        |
                               |  Done()                                                |
                               |                                                        |
                               |                                                        |
                               |                                                        |
                            <Idle> ---------------------->------------------------------+
```

As a consequence *Motor* also inherits those states.

Now, if *Motor* is in the *Init* state, calling the Start() method will change the state from *Init* to *Ready*.

Depending on the architecture of your program this change can have an immediate effect  on the program flow (this means in the **current cycle**)  or in the **next cycle**.

Let's say, our StateMachine Function Block implements *Cycle-Internal* as a boolean input variable: *bCycleInternal* 
and it's current state as an enumaration variable: *eStateMachine*

Let's also say that, depending on the value of eStateMachine (thus the current state of the state machine), StateMachine calls a specific method (e.g. for *Init* Init(), for *Ready* Ready() etc.)

When bCycleInternal is true and the Start() method changes the current state from *Init* to *Ready*, Ready() is called **directly** after Init() in the **same cycle**.
Otherwise, if bCycleInternal is false, when changing the state of the state machine (or the value of eStateMachine) from *Init* to *Ready* with the Start() method, Ready() is called **not before** the **next cycle**.

Comment: Read the question carefully. "during the same plc cycle/simulink step" it is not possible to perform 2 different steps within one PLC cycle!

Comment: Read the documentation carefully:"Integrated in the TwinCAT 3 Development System, a statechart has an editor with state elements and transition elements. When compiling the application, executable code is generated. The transition behavior of a statechart during executing depends on the task cycle. But it can switch independed as well. Then, it is an in-cycle"https://infosys.beckhoff.com/content/1033/tf1910_tc3_uml/72057594862702475.html?id=3677255956364428212

Comment: So yes, as in structured text, it is possible to do 2 different steps within 1 cycle..

Comment: The link you gave me is to UML chats. I cannot find there confirmation of your statement. I am still cannot understand how it could work. Although I have to admit that I have never worked with TwinCat, so I may allow something like exists.

Comment: Thank you so much for the helpful answer. To make sure I get this correctly, I can think of 2 cases where the above might violate real time constraints. Added them to the Post.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible. It is completely dependent on how you define your state machine code. The answer by Filippo explains how the Cycle-Internal option could be used.

Another way to look at this is that in Structured Text normally a state machine would be implemented with a Case structure.

In order to have multiple states within a single cycle you would require two Case structures or run the same Case structure twice (With a For or While loop for example)

For example if let's say you would like to act on an error state as soon as you move to the error state. Your first Case statement would transition the state to "Error".

In your second Case statement you would check for an "Error" state and act on it immediately.

Comment: Read the question carefully. "during the same plc cycle/simulink step" it is not possible to perform 2 different steps within one PLC cycle!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is helpful for older versions where state charts are not supported and have to be implemented with CASE structures.

Comment: Structured text is the common plc language for advanced and complex projects.Frameworks are normally written in Structured Text whereas State charts are used when you want to visualize a process step-chains in order to make it easier for maintanance or service staff to debug or perhaps fix it.